# Enable State Recording Suddenly Got Disabled

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I am developing a Windows Store App with xaml and C#. I have been trying to adjust my UI for different states for some time. I replaced my MainPage with the previous version due to some issues (previous version is a few days old with no significant changes except a couple method names). After that 'enable state recording' checkbox got disabled. Any ideas?

I also wrapped my maingrid in a viewbox before state recording got disabled. Can anyone tell me what happened?

Comment: Do you still have a `VisualStateManager` with defined StateGroup/States to record against? Have you embedded it in some sort of Template and you aren't actually currently editing that particular Template your VSM lives in? Also, generally one wouldn't expect a whole "maingrid" to be embedded in a `ViewBox` but that's another thing all together.

Comment: Yes the VisualStateManager is still there in that page with all the previous view changes I made.

Comment: Viewbox is the issue. Thanks for helping